# How to calculate the Cartesian Power of a list in R

Tags: r, algorithm, set, cartesian-product

I want to generate the Cartesian **power** of an arbitrary set in R.
For example in Python I would do it in the following way:

```
from itertools import product
c = [1, 2, 3]
n = 2
l = list(product(c, repeat=n))
```

This results in the following output.

```
[(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(3, 3)]
```

I am quite new to R so I was wondering if there was a built-in function that I could use to achieve this. Note that I am particularly interested in increasing the power (repeat parameter in Python).

Comment: `do.call("expand.grid", rep(list(1:3), 2))` gives the output shown in the question.  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rje/versions/1.10.10/topics/powerSet gives the power set.  `t(combn(1:3, 2))` gives unique combinations of length 2.

Comment: wouldn't `expand.grid(1:3,1:3)` achieve basically the same result ?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck The expand.grid function does not suffice for arbitrary sets, such as c(1, 3, 7). Is there are workaround for this?

Comment: @Base_R_Best_R I want to explicitly control the amount of times the product is calculated for arbitrary sets. So this would also mean for example expand.grid(c(1,4,9), c(1,4,9), c(1,4,9)) . I am looking for a function with a parameter n which specifies the amount of times the product is calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @G.Grothendieck for solving the question!

```
s <- c(1, 2, 3)
n <- 2
do.call("expand.grid", rep(list(s), n))
```

This is the R code that gives the correct results.

Comment: If this answers your question,  please upvote and accept it as the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Or shorter: `expand.grid(rep(list(s), n))`

Answer (score 3):

The suggested solution ignores order. You will note that `expand.grid` iterates the ***leftmost element on each iteration***, which does not yield the same order as python's `itertools.product` generator. Observe:

```
s <- c(1, 2, 3)
n <- 2
do.call("expand.grid", rep(list(s), n))
  Var1 Var2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    1    2    <-- This is the second result using python's product
5    2    2
6    3    2
7    1    3    <-- This is the third result using python's product
8    2    3
9    3    3
```

Compared with the output from the python solution:

```
from itertools import product
c = [1, 2, 3]
n = 2

list(product(c, repeat=n))
[(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 1),
(3, 2),
(3, 3)]
```

From the [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) documentation (emphasis mine):

> The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the ***rightmost element advancing on every iteration.*** This pattern creates a lexicographic ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product tuples are emitted in sorted order.

Compare this with what was stated at the top of this answer (i.e. leftmost).

Fortunately, generating the exact same output in `R` (or any language for that matter) is relatively easy as these are simply permutations with repetition. If you wanted to build your own generator like `python`, the algorithm is relatively simple as suggested by the documentation (i.e. *"Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression*").

There are a few packages capable of generating these rather efficiently in the desired order. They are `gtools`, `arrangements`, and `RcppAlgos` <sup>*</sup>.

Here is the code for all three:

```
gtools::permutations(3, 2, repeats.allowed = T)

arrangements::permutations(3, 2, replace = T)

RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(3, 2, T)
```

As a benefit, these solutions are more efficient that using `expand.grid`:

```
system.time(do.call("expand.grid", rep(list(1:7), 8)))
 user  system elapsed 
0.375   0.007   0.382

system.time(RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(7, 8, T))
 user  system elapsed 
0.057   0.032   0.088

RcppAlgos::permuteCount(7, 8, T)
[1] 5764801
```

In fact, they are even faster than the `python` solution:

```
import time

def getTime():
     start = time.time()
     list(product([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], repeat = 8))
     end = time.time()
     print(end - start)

getTime()
0.9604620933532715
```

To be fair, `itertools` is meant to be *iterated* thus memory efficient and not really meant to generate all results at once.

<sup>*</sup> I am the author of `RcppAlgos`